# pandas iterate over column values at once and generate range

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, tuples

I have a pandas dataframe like as below

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'biz': [18, 23], 'seg': [30, 34], 'PID': [40, 52]})
```

I would like to do the below

a) pass all the values from each column at once to for loop

For ex:

I am trying the below

```
cols = ['biz','seg','PID']
for col in cols:
  for i, j in df1.col.values:
      print("D" + str(i) + ":" + "F" + str(j))
      print("Q" + str(i) + ":" + "S" + str(j))
      print("AB" + str(i) + ":" + "AD" + str(j))
```

but this doesn;t work and I get an error

> TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable numpy.int64 object

I expect my output to be like as below

```
D18:F23
Q18:S23
AB18:AD23
D30:F34
Q30:S34
AB30:AD34
D40:F52
Q40:S52
AB40:AD52
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mistake is in the innermost forloop.

You are requesting an iterator over a 1-dimensional array of values, this iterator yields scalar values and hence they can not be unpacked.

If your dataframe only has 2 items per column, then this should suffice

```
cols = ['biz','seg','PID']
for col in cols:
   i, j = getattr(df1, col).values
   print("D" + str(i) + ":" + "F" + str(j))
   print("Q" + str(i) + ":" + "S" + str(j))
   print("AB" + str(i) + ":" + "AD" + str(j))
```

### Alternatives

#### Pandas using `loc`

This is actually the simplest way to solve it but only now it occurred to me. We use the column name `col` along with `loc` to get all rows (given by `:` in `loc[:, col]`)

```
cols = ['biz','seg','PID']
for col in cols:
    i, j = df1.loc[:, col].values
```

#### Attrgetter

We can use the attrgetter object from `operator` library to get a single (or as many attributes) as we want:

```
from operator import attrgetter

cols = ['biz','seg','PID']
cols = attrgetter(*cols)(df1)
for col in cols:
   i, j = col.values
```

#### Attrgetter 2

This approach is similar to the one above, except that we select multiple columns and have the i and j in two lists, with each entry corresponding to one column.

```
from operator import attrgetter

cols = ['biz','seg','PID']
cols = attrgetter(*cols)(df1)
cols = [col.values for col in cols]
all_i, all_j = zip(*cols)
```

#### Pandas solution

This approach uses just pandas functions. It gets the column index using the `df1.columns.get_loc(col_name)` function, and then uses `.iloc` to index the values. In `.iloc[a,b]` we use `:` in place of a to select all rows, and `index` in place of b to select just the column.

```
cols = ['biz','seg','PID']
for col in cols:
    index = df1.columns.get_loc(col)
    i, j = df1.iloc[:, index]
    # do the printing here
```

Comment: wow. nice. I am learning about `getattr` just now. So, this just gets the column values like `unique()`? nice

Comment: other than `getattr`, is there any other way to get `i` and `j` from each column? I mean without using `getattr`, how would you get `i` and `j`?

Comment: @TheGreat I have added some more solutions that avoid using `getattr`, some of which use just pandas code.

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in range(len(df1)):
    print('D' + str(df1.iloc[i,0]) + ':' + 'F' + str(df1.iloc[i+1,0]))
    print('Q' + str(df1.iloc[i,0]) + ':' + 'S' + str(df1.iloc[i+1,0]))
    print('AB' + str(df1.iloc[i,0]) + ':' + 'AD' + str(df1.iloc[i+1,0]))
    print('D' + str(df1.iloc[i,1]) + ':' + 'F' + str(df1.iloc[i+1,1]))
    print('Q' + str(df1.iloc[i,1]) + ':' + 'S' + str(df1.iloc[i+1,1]))
    print('AB' + str(df1.iloc[i,1]) + ':' + 'AD' + str(df1.iloc[i+1,1]))
    print('D' + str(df1.iloc[i,2]) + ':' + 'F' + str(df1.iloc[i+1,2]))
    print('Q' + str(df1.iloc[i,2]) + ':' + 'S' + str(df1.iloc[i+1,2]))
    print('AB' + str(df1.iloc[i,2]) + ':' + 'AD' + str(df1.iloc[i+1,2]))
```

Comment: WELCOME to SO. you wish to write some explanation of the code?